# Function redefinition's legal in java?

Tags: java

Eclipse allows me to run this by simply pressing a proceed button in a "Error in work-space" dialog:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void foo()
    {
    }

    public static void foo()
    {
    }

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    }
}
```

[image]

Does this mean that function redefinition's like these are legal?

Comment: If I try this in eclipse it will give me an error, it could have something to do with it being a static function

Comment: _Eclipse allows me to run this by simply pressing a proceed button:_ Then your eclipse is not working properly, uninstall and reinstall it.

Comment: it must give you `Duplicate method foo() in type Main`

Comment: Try rebuilding the project and then running.

Comment: Eclipse is drunk i guess

Comment: The screenshot comes from the second computer iv'e tried this on, it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eclipse allows you to run code which doesn't compile.  It replaces such code with `throw new Error("whatever the compilation error was");` I consider this a very BAD (Broken As Designed) feature but others love it.

In your case this works because you don't use the function anyway.

Answer (score 2):

**no** it is illegal, it must differ in method signature

Answer (score 2):

Two methods are prohibited from having the same signature this won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

check again, you should get following error

`Duplicate method foo() in type MainClass`